# A more elegant way to compare two Android Rect position?

Tags: android

Now I have two Android [Rect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect) and want to know the relative position between them such as check if Rect B is to the right of Rect A or if Rect B is to the top of Rect A.

Just for reference, the coordinates of Android device screen works like following:

1. (0, 0) is top left corner.
2. (maxX, 0) is top right corner
3. (0, maxY) is bottom left corner
4. (maxX, maxY) is bottom right corner

```
private boolean between(int variable, int minValueInclusive, int maxValueInclusive) {
    return variable >= minValueInclusive && variable <= maxValueInclusive;
}

private boolean isAtRight(Rect rectA, Rect rectB) {
    /* Checks if Rect B is to the right of Rect A. */
    if ((between(rectB.top, rectA.top, rectA.bottom) || between(rectB.bottom, rectA.top, rectA.bottom)) && rectB.left >= rectA.right) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to implement this. Because the IF statement here is a little bit long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private boolean isAtRight(Rect rectA, Rect rectB) {
    /* Checks if Rect B is to the right of Rect A. */
    return rectA.top <= rectB.bottom && rectA.bottom >= rectB.top && rectB.left >= rectA.right
}
```

The first part of the if statement is false only when A is fully below B.
The second part of it is false only when A is fully above B.
So basically everything else is somewhere between (same as in your example). And the third part of your if statement stayed the same.

And the `between()` method is no longer needed.